# How to add a button counter AND href in php/HTML

Tags: php, html, href

I have found some code to make a counter in php (simple, without using a database). The counter is implemented with some small php code that triggers when click_installer becomes yes. I need to put this code into a href (according to the original code), but I also need a href for the link to go to.
How can I combine two href statements in one href so both the counter and link works. 
What I now have is:

```
 <h3><a   href="?click_installer=yes" href="http://pcgtools.mkspace.nl/PcgTools.zip" 
  >PCG Tools 1.8.1 Installer (.zip)</a></h3>
```

In this solution, only the first href works, so the counter is updated.

If I switch the href commands like:

```
 <h3><a href="http://pcgtools.mkspace.nl/PcgTools.zip" href="?click_installer=yes" 
   >PCG Tools 1.8.1 Installer (.zip)</a></h3>
```

only the link will work and the counter will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. Link to your script. Issue a `Location` header to redirect to the other file.
2. Fetch the counter URL using JavaScript, then let the `href` be followed
3. Forget about writing code to store a count. You've got a webserver, just examine the server log files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm a total noob regarding php, I think I need some more info, espeically regarding 1 and 2. I don't see why a file is not good ... I don't use a webserver.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=location+header+php - but you're going to run running a website using PHP **very** hard without a webserver.

Comment: It seems to work ... except that I need to refresh the screen to see the count update, but thanks!